# Permutation and combination regarding two people together

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

You have 11 friends and can invite 5 to dinner 1) in how many ways if two of the friends married and will not attend separately? 2) in how many ways if two of them are not on speaking terms and will not attend together?

Comment: are the two friends married with two who are also friends?

Comment: or even are the two married not on speaking terms ? a regretably common situation. One assumes that the two parts of the question are separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) as (1a) the two married plus 3 out of the remaining 9 plus (1b) 5 out of the 9 excluding the married.

(2) as (2a) one of the two plus 4 out of the remaining 9 (excluding 1 and her enemy) plus 2(b) the same again for the other of the two.

(1a) = 1. $^9C_3$ = $9!/3!.6!$ = 84

(1b) = $^9C_5$ = $9!/5!. 4!$ = 18

(1) = 102.

(2) = $2. ^9C_4$ = $2. 9!/5!.4!$ = 36.